# Writing an object oriented multithreaded job\result queue in python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

long time lurker here.

I have a thread controller object.  This object takes in other objects called "Checks".  These Checks pull in DB rows that match their criteria.  The thread manager polls each check (asking it for it's DB rows aka work units) and then enqueues each row along with a reference to that check object.  The thought is that N many threads will come in and pull off an item from the queue and execute the corresponding Check's do_work method.  The do_work method will return Pass\Fail and all passes will be enqueued for further processing.

The main script (not shown) instantiates the checks and adds them to the thread manager using add_check and then calls kick_off_work.

So far I am testing and it simply locks up:

```
  import Queue
  from threading import Thread

  class ThreadMan:

    def __init__(self, reporter):
            print "Initializing thread manager..."
            self.workQueue = Queue.Queue()
            self.resultQueue = Queue.Queue()
            self.checks = []

    def add_check(self, check):
            self.checks.append(check)

    def kick_off_work(self):
            for check in self.checks:
                    for work_unit in check.populate_work():
                            #work unit is a DB row
                            self.workQueue.put({"object" : check, "work" : work_unit})


            threads = Thread(target=self.execute_work_unit)
            threads = Thread(target=self.execute_work_unit)
            threads.start()
            self.workQueue.join();

    def execute_work_unit(self):
            unit = self.workQueue.get()
            check_object = unit['object'] #Check object
            work_row = unit['work'] # DB ROW

            check_object.do_work(work_row)
            self.workQueue.task_done();
            print "Done with work!!"
```

The output is simply:

```
Initializing thread manager...
In check1's do_work method... Doing work
Done with work!!

(locked up)
```

I would like to run through the entire queue

Answer (score 0):

you should only add a "while" in your execute_work_unit otherwise it stops at first iteration:

```
def execute_work_unit(self):
     while True:
        unit = self.workQueue.get()
        check_object = unit['object'] #Check object
        work_row = unit['work'] # DB ROW

        check_object.do_work(work_row)
        self.workQueue.task_done();
        print "Done with work!!"
```

have a look there:
    http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue

EDIT: to get it finish just add threads.join() after your self.workQueue.join() in 
def kick_off_work(self):

Comment: Thanks a lot.  All the work executes now, but it still hangs at the end.

Comment: what do you mean by hangs? (i'm not native english)

Comment: It doesn't finish executing.